# Creating text documents in MVC (PDF and DOCX)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

So I have been googling my head off, with no result, so hoping someone here have a solution or suggestion on how to create .pdf and .docx files in MVC

Many thanks

Comment: For pdf creation you can use third party applications such as iTextSharp. Ford docx., not sure.

Comment: For docx, you can use the OpenXML SDK: https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/cc850833.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For mvc create pdf files one of the best (imho) is

https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa

Some code example:

```
public ActionResult PrintIndex()
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("Index", new { name = "Giorgio" }) { FileName = "Test.pdf" };
}

public ActionResult Index(string name)
{
    ViewBag.Message = string.Format("Hello {0} to ASP.NET MVC!", name);

    return View();
}
```